# How to get structured object using POST endpoint in SvelteKit?

Tags: object, svelte, endpoint, sveltekit

when I'm using the POST endpoint from Sveltekit, I get a "flat" object as output. How can I get a "structured" Object instead ?

Let's assume the following code:

index.svelte

```html
<div class="container">
  <form method="post">
    <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" />

    <label for="lastname">Lastname</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" />

    <label for="dog">Dog 1</label>
    <input type="text" name="dog" />

    <label for="dog">Dog 2</label>
    <input type="text" name="dog" />

    <!-- ... -->

    <button>Save</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

index.js

```js
export async function post({request}){
    const data = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());
    console.log(data);

    return{}
}
```

Ouput (what I'm calling "flat" object)

```js
{ firstname: 'foo', lastname: 'bar', dog: 'teckel', dog: 'labrador' }
```

Instead of that output, how should I proceed to get the following one in my index.js

Expected output:

```js
{
  firstname: 'foo',
  lastname: 'bar',
  dogs: [ { dog: 'teckel' }, { dog: 'labrador' } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are libraries that can perform a transform like this more or less automated. Some use conventions in the field names to parse the data into arrays and nested structures, others additionally use schemas to do type conversions or validation. E.g. to achieve an array of objects like this, one might set the names like this:

```html
<label for="dog">Dog 1</label>
<input type="text" name="dogs[][dog]" />

<label for="dog">Dog 2</label>
<input type="text" name="dogs[][dog]" />
```

The `[]` Indicates that the field is part of an array, `[dog]` indicates that a property called `dog` is set on the element (`.dog` would also be reasonable).

So instead of calling `Object.fromEntries` you have to either parse the data yourself or find a library that does it for you. (Note that StackOverflow is *not* a place for library recommendations.)

---

Personally, I would avoid the synchronous form post and send JSON asynchronously instead, that way you can send in a fixed structure and receive that exact structure. Of course this requires binding/reading the form values yourself and the form will not work as intended if the JS failed to load.

Comment: thanks for your answer. applying the async method (with a handlesubmit, like this: https://svelte.dev/repl/78f20ec2679d48599971cbdf39733faa?version=3.48.0 . After posting i'm using the goto function from '$app/navigation' but I need to reload the page to see the newly created item appearing... How should I proceed then ?

Comment: @Henri If you go the async route you have to make dealing with the response async as well. So in this case the endpoint that adds the item should return the new item, again as JSON, which then can be added to some array that is rendered to the page. (You need to `await` the fetch which gives you a response object and then `await response.json()`  to get the data.) Unfortunately it seems that contrary to what the SvelteKit documentation states, the endpoints will return HTML rather than JSON and setting the `Content-Type` header does not change that either. Not sure what to do about that...

Comment: @Henri So, for the endpoint to be able to actually return JSON, the **request** has to set a header of `'accept': 'application/json'`, otherwise you always get HTML.. [Example REPL for client-side code](https://svelte.dev/repl/b6c2dd6ceeee40088c341a5c7f30ac20?version=3.48.0)