# How do I create a nice Object from my form submitted fields?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Having problems trying to figure out how to get the transaction and amount form fields into a nice object (in the handleSubmit function)...

Would like to have something like:

```
transactions [
          transaction[0] {
                    type: type1,
                    value: 1
          },
          transaction[1] {
                    type: type2,
                    value: 2
          },
          ....
]
```

**Any suggestions?**

```
<script>
    function handleSubmit(e) {
        const formData= new (formData.target)
    }
</script>

<form on:submit|preventDefault={addTodo} method="POST">
 {#each Array(10) as transaction, i}
   <div id="row-{i}">
      <input type="text" name="type" />
      <input name="text" name="amount" />
   </div>
{/each}

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get structured object using POST endpoint in SvelteKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72520724/how-to-get-structured-object-using-post-endpoint-in-sveltekit)

Comment: (Getting an object client-side is not the hard part, for that you just need to use [`bind:value`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-bind-property) on the inputs to bind them to local state objects. If you struggle with that, I could add an answer.)